# How to use URLImage class in codenameone netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

i want to use the URLImage class in my current project but can't seem to find it in my current version of codenameone running on netbeans 7.4. How do I incorperate it into my IDE? I tried downloading the latest plugin but it did not do the job. Any tips? As I find the ImageDownloadService confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries are updated by going to the project properties Codename One section and clicking the update client libs button.